# Proper construction of query in SQL Server administration to form builder applications

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help getting a stored procedure constructed that will be used to handle cases where a user may either update existing data or insert new data.

Specifically I'm working on an application that is a basic form builder and will consists of fields and textboxes. Users may add new fields and textboxes to a form or remove them. They may also decide to later change the text of an existing field.

Here is what I currently have. Which is not working as I'd like and I understand the "like" is the problem, but I'm not sure how to properly construct the query.

With what I currently have if a field is named "Address1" and "Address2" and the user wants to edit the fields to be "Address" and "Address1" both fields will end up being renamed to "Address1".

Here is my stored procedure currently:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT WidgetText FROM FormBuilderFormFields 
               WHERE FormId = @formid AND WidgetText LIKE @widgetText + '%')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO FormBuilderFormFields (FormId, [Required], SortOrder, CreateDate, CreatedBy, WidgetId, WidgetText, WidgetVals, WidgetInputType)
    VALUES (@formid, @required, @sortOrder, @createDate, @uid, @widgetId, @widgetText, @widgetVals, @widgetInputType)           
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE FormBuilderFormFields 
    SET [Required] = @required,
        SortOrder = @sortOrder,
        CreateDate = @createDate,
        CreatedBy = @uid,       
        WidgetId = @widgetId,
        WidgetText = @widgetText,
        WidgetVals = @widgetVals,
        WidgetInputType = @widgetInputType      
    WHERE   
        FieldId = (SELECT FieldId FROM FormBuilderFormFields 
                   WHERE WidgetText = (SELECT WidgetText 
                                       FROM FormBuilderFormFields 
                                       WHERE FormId = @formid 
                                         AND WidgetText LIKE @widgetText + '%'))-- AND FormId = @formid)
END
```

I'd greatly appreciate some help with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `LIKE`. The wildcard means it matches all of `Address1`,  `Address2` and `Address Goes Here`. Use `=` instead.

Comment: OK ! : ) it can be improved